# Why is the downloadable HTML different from Inspector HTML?

Tags: html, firefox, web-scraping

https://nestiolistings.com/p/listing/2388/1830290/10/4t4-2d28281a185d15467a11/?utm_source=email-blast&utm_medium=inline

This is just one example. If I download the webpage, the HTML I get is vastly different from what I see in the Inspector in Firefox. In fact, it's missing all of the data I'm trying to get at. Please help me to understand the disparity, and if there's some way to access the Inspector HTML for scraping purposes. Thanks!

Comment: A webpage is made up of far more than a single html page, the answer to your question is probably javascript

Comment: Inspector shows code after running JavaScript.

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: Sorry I'm using BeautifulSoup but forgot it wasn't particularly relevant. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using requests or similar to get the html directly. Please not this does not execute javascript. So if the site uses javascript to render content you'll be missing that in your script.

You can use Selenium to start up a real browser from code and make sure javascript is executed. I'd try that in this case to see if that gives you the expected content

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://nestiolistings.com/p/listing/2388/1830290/10/4t4-2d28281a185d15467a11/?utm_source=email-blast&utm_medium=inline")

print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look into selenium a little more as unfortunately, using your code seemed to give me the same result as before, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: It says there's a file for the browsers that needs to be located at "PATH" but I don't know where or what that is. It gives the examples of /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin and I can't find either if those. If you have some idea, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: that's probably for the driver = webdriver.Chrome() line? 
you can download chromedriver for instance here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ 
Then you need to include the filepath to this file in that line of code
wedriver.Chrom('/some/file/path/chromedriver')

Comment: Thanks again. What's the syntax for using the drive letter in the file path name?

Comment: Scratch that. Figured it out. Got the Firefox driver working and now it's giving me the results I want. Thank you so much again!